# Register class type with numeric identifier

Tags: c++, variables, types, identifier

I've got an **entity class**, a **base component class** and a few **base component derived** ones. The entity class contains an array of base component pointers:

```
class CComponent
{
public:
  static unsigned GetType() { return -1; }; //Base identifier 
  //...
};
```

---

```
class CPoint : CComponent
{
  public:
    static unsigned GetType() { return 0; }; //Point identifier 
}
```

---

```
class CEntity
{
private:
  CComponent* aComponents[3];
public:
  // ... 
  //Getter by component ID here!
};
```

---

I would like to know how can I map a specific component **type** along with its integer identifier (for the **CPoint** component class, it would be 0) so I can easily cast it to the right type, in my Entity class.

**Example**: Suppose I've added a CPoint component to the entity component array (in position 0 of course), and I want to retrieve it as a CPoint (type-casting) by inputting the component **integer identifier** (in this case, 0). I want to avoid huge 'switch' cases as much as possible!

PS: I don't want to use loads of virtual functions in my base component class that match with properties in my derived ones. (I don't want to have a virtual SetPos function in my base component class, while it's place is in the CPoint class);

PS#2: As commented by 'etarion', I would like something like this:

```
dynamic_cast<get_type_for(0)*>(obj)
```

Of course, that's the mechanism I want to achieve, I don't know if it's possible or not.

Comment: to clarify, when you saying "inputting component integer", what do you want that function signature to look like - i.e. should it accept an index (in the component array) and the type you want, or should it take a type and return the first instance of that type from the array?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you give an example how you want to use this, in actual code, if you knew how to do it? It sounds like you want to `dynamic_cast<get_type_for(0)*>(obj)` (which doesn't work of course), and that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea @ etarion. (with the dynamic_cast<get_type_for(0)*>) The component array can only have one component type at a time, indexed by the components integer identifier. So the Point component will always be in the aComponents[0] spot.

Comment: sounds like what you need is a variant type (see boost::variant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I know of some ways to achieve the sort of thing you want :

- with gcc you can use the *non standard* `typeof(some_type)` function which gives you the type to dynamically cast your type. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html).
- with [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Type_inference) there is a standard way that mimics typeof : `decltype(some_type)`
- you can use the standard `typeid` that gives you a [type_info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) class which implements `operator==`
- [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/variant.html) is another way mentioned in one of the comment (I do know it well ...)

my2c